# Enable Password Prompt for Windows Recovery Environment

Tags: windows-7, password

On one of my domain workstations I'm able to access the Windows 7 Recovery Environment (WinRE) *without* being prompted for a username and password. My research ([example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11028.how-to-access-windows-recovery-environment-in-windows-7.aspx)) unanimously declares I'm supposed to get the following prompt to login with a local user account immediately after selecting the keyboard input method:

[image]

**I never get this prompt**.

This TechNet [forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1e6108a9-f6e3-44fe-945e-b3a96409c87c/disable-winre-password-promt?forum=w7itproinstall) by a Moderator confirms I should be prompted to logon and *this is not a configurable option*:

> When using WinRE, Administrative privilege is demanded by design and this cannot be disabled.

Yet without logging in, I'm able to access all of the recovery options, including the Command Prompt, in which I can navigate all of the data on the machine's hard drive.

The only local accounts on the machine are the `Administrator` and `Guest` accounts, both which are disabled.  The Administrator account has a password set.

I'm booting to WinRE from a USB drive created from Windows 7 Pro OEM System Builder media. It's not a customized WinRE environment. The %USERNAME% variable in the WinRE Command Prompt reports I'm logged in as SYSTEM. The computer in question is a domain member running Windows 7 Pro 64-bit with the latest updates.

The group policy setting *Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Recovery console: Allow automatic administrative logon* is Disabled, which [means](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852192(v=ws.11).aspx):

> Automatic administrative logon is not allowed.

#### How can I troubleshoot this and require user logon to access WinRE?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the policy setting (gpedit.msc and/or gpresult /h):

Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options:  Recovery console: Allow automatic administrative logon

[image]

[image]

Registry setting:

```
Key: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Setup\RecoveryConsole\  
Value: SecurityLevel (0 = disabled)
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/security-policy-settings/recovery-console-allow-automatic-administrative-logon

Comment: I'll check this, but I thought this policy doesn't apply to Vista+ because of the Recovery Console being replaced with WinRE....?

Comment: No dice. The policy `Allow automatic administrative logon` is Disabled and the registry value **SecurityLevel** is set with a value of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to boot from USB or optical drive always means that the data on hard drive is browsable if you have physical access to the machine and the hard drive is not encrypted.

A standard recovery console *can obey* the `Recovery console: Allow automatic administrative logon = disabled` Group Policy (or the registry key), but a recovery system on an external drive doesn't *need to* care about your domain user privileges or local authentication methods. A recovery system can just access the hard drive completely outside the system. Other tools like [ntpasswd](https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) or any Linux live distribution does that.

Therefore, if you want to explicitly prevent users from accessing *any* recovery environment:

- Add BIOS / UEFI password.
- Exclude anything but local hard drive from boot order & boot options.
- Remove recovery partitions from hard drive.
- Possibly encrypt the drive (e.g. with BitLocker) if you also want to limit access with a screwdriver.

Comment: At the end of the day, when access to WinRE is needed to perform legitimate system maintenance, I want the machine to challenge the user for credentials as designed. You state *"The recovery system on external drive doesn't care about your domain user privileges or local authentication methods. It just accesses the hard drive as a SYSTEM account."* Can you cite an authoritative source that confirms this?

Comment: I could do more research on that particular environment and either reinforce or alter that claim. I'd first like to know what kind of (daily?) maintenance requires users to use WinRE? I bet there must be tools designed for such operations.

Comment: Certainly not daily. On well-maintained systems use of WinRE is a rare event indeed, but I've used it to get systems to boot that otherwise would be unfixable (e.g. faulty driver that Startup Repair and/or System Restore could not fix).

Comment: I'd still recommend having BIOS/UEFI password to protect the boot options. This kind of maintenance operations are probably IT department's cases anyway, so the extra layer of password shouldn't be a real limitation.